# Where should I write parent dependent styles for child component?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using Styled components in a small example like this.

```
    <Container>
          <Child/>
          <Sibling/>
    </Container>
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
    display: grid;
`;
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Child = styled.div`
    justify-self:end;
`;
```

My container could be flex or a grid container.
And I want my Child and Sibling Component to be re-usable components, and thus should be independent of how the parent is implemented.

My doubt is where do I apply properties like justify-self and align-self that are very dependent on the parent component?

So far I've been wrapping child in a div and styling that div for these parent dependant styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Compound Components pattern. Your code might look like this:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
    display: grid;
`;

const Child = styled.div`
    justify-self:end;
`;
// I know the name of this is unfortunate. It's just an examle. Maybe 'Column' will be better or something like that.

Container.Child = Child

<Container>
  <Cointainer.Child>
    <Child />
  </Container.Child>
  <Cointainer.Child>
    <Sibling />
  </Container.Child>
</Container>
```

You can find out more about it here: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks

Comment: what if I want different Styles for Child and Sibling both? Do I create Container.Child and Container.Sibling ?

Comment: You can pass props for the Container.Child component or create a new component (eg. Row and Column). But all the styles of nested components should be in these components.
Container.Child will be responsible only for the layout.